# How to execute one function after completion of another

Tags: swiftui

I have been trying to execute `getData()` after the completion of `login()`, but that never seems to work when using `DispatchQueue.main.async`

I have only been able to get it to work by forcing a delay, what's the best way to go about this?
Thanks

```
class DataTask {
    func login{...}
    func getData{...}
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var data = DataTask()
    var body: some View{
        Text("Hello world")
        .onAppear{
            data.login()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0){
                func refreshData(){
                    data.getData()
                    // update the response into core data
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to call getData() from within the end of login() function.

Answer (score 0):

Never use hard-coded delays to work around an asynchronous task, that's a horrible practice.

To *execute* a function *after the completion* of another add a completion handler

```
class DataTask {
    func login(completion: @escaping: () -> Void) {... completion() ...}
    func getData {...}
}

...

data.login {
   data.getData()
}
```